# Swift player freezes but audio still works in background when switching videos from collection view

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, avplayer

Here's a quick video of what I mean: https://youtu.be/Ld8apahZBIg

I have a collection view and when I click any first video to play it displays it perfectly. When I click back to close the player/view to play a different video, the audio works in the background but the video display seems to freeze when playing the video.

Here's the relevant code for the UICollectionView:

```
class HomeController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

       override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
         collectionView?.register(HomePostCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)

    collectionView?.register(HomeControllerHeader.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "HomeControllerHeaderId")
   }

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return posts.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 1
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! HomePostCell
    //        self.hpc = cell
    cell.post = posts[indexPath.item]
    return cell
} 

var avPlayerViewController = VideoPlayerViewController()

var avPlayer = AVPlayer()
var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer!

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let links = posts[indexPath.row]
    guard let url = NSURL(string: links.videoUrl) else { return }
    var player = avPlayerViewController.player
    player = AVPlayer(url: url as URL)
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url as URL)
    avPlayer.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem)
    let playerController = avPlayerViewController
    playerController.player = player

self.navigationController?.pushViewController(playerController, animated: true)
        playerController.player.play()

      }
}
```

Here's the relevant code for my avPlayer View Controller class:

```
class VideoPlayerViewController: UIViewController {
    var player: AVPlayer!
    var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer!

    let videoView: UIView = {
       let vidView = UIView()
       return vidView
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)

        videoView.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)

        view.addSubview(videoView)

        videoView.anchor(top: view.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(true)
        playerLayer.frame = view.bounds
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
        player!.play()
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        playerLayer.frame = view.bounds
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        player!.pause()
        player = nil
        playerLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
    }
}
```

Let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: "I have a collection view"  You don't have a single line in your code suggesting so.

Comment: @ElTomato Okay, I added the collection view class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it. The problem was that I was calling the player to display the video once. Every time I tried to remove the sublayer and play a new video the video player would freeze because would happen because the player layer would only load once, and then when tried to play a new player layer it wouldn't because it needed to load again. I used viewDidAppear to load things every time view controller is displayed.

```
class VideoPlayerViewController: UIViewController {


var hc: HomeController!
var player: AVPlayer!
var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer!

let videoView: UIView = {
   let vidView = UIView()
   return vidView
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .black
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)
    playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    view.addSubview(videoView)
    videoView.anchor(top: view.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
    playerLayer.frame = view.bounds
    player!.play()
}

override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    player!.pause()
    player = nil
    playerLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
}

}
```

Comment: Hii i am using collectionviewcell facing same issue any help ?